# SwiftUI ViewBuilder can't pass in different views

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewbuilder

In Swift/SwiftUI, I'm trying to make a custom view, which takes other views as arguments. However, I'm getting the error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`.

I know that this error is usually due to mismatching types. Also, in the implementation below, having 2 `Text` views causes no error, but using a `Text` view as well as an `Image` view causes an error.

This makes me believe that the error is due to the fact that `Image` and `Text` are technically different types. However, since they both conform to `View`, and because my `CustomView` has both parameters of type `View`, I don't understand why this issue is happening.

```
struct CustomView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var label: Content
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            self.label

            self.content
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView {             //<-- ERROR: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
            Image(systemName: "person.3.fill")
        } content: {
            Text("")
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this error? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in `CustomView` you defined both `label` and `content` as views of a single type (generic `Content`), but you pass different kinds to the initializer.

One way to fix it is to define different types for `label` and `content`:

```swift
struct CustomView<Label: View, Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder let label: Label
    @ViewBuilder let content: Content

    // The rest is unchanged.
```